# how to remove a property from wcf response xml

Tags: wcf

I don't want to show the property in my xml response when it does not contain data.

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
List<Details>
```

I will be having data to this property in some scenarios and will not have data in this property in some scenarios. I do not want this property in my xml response when I do not have data in it.

Comment: shortened title and used code format for extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to implement it by initializing my property in the constructor as null and initializing it again in my API when the data is present for that property.